# Issue with r8711 wi-fi usb after wake up from sleep

Tags: wireless, usb, hibernate, realtek

I have issue with restore from sleep mode on ubuntu 13.04
    Linux 3.8.0-28-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP

```
[25944.029996] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[25944.304744] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan3: link is not ready
[25944.418469] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth1: link down
[25944.418552] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[25944.439853] r8712u: in r8711_wx_set_scan: bDriverStopped=1
[25944.439975] r8712u: in r8711_wx_set_scan: bDriverStopped=1
[25945.580319] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[25967.754316] r8712u: in r8711_wx_set_scan: bDriverStopped=1
[25981.900796] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan3: link is not ready
[25981.922257] r8712u: in r8711_wx_set_scan: bDriverStopped=1
[25981.922378] r8712u: in r8711_wx_set_scan: bDriverStopped=1
[26004.746640] r8712u: in r8711_wx_set_scan: bDriverStopped=1
```

But if I do  those commands

```
$ sudo modprobe r8712u 
$ sudo modprobe r8712u
```

O just reconnect usb-dongle, wifi begin works. It's inconvenient. Seems like a but for me. Any suggestions? On fresh installed netrunner( based on that version ubuntu) no that issue at all. Seems for me that update from Ubuntu LTS went wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, and while not a solution, this is a workaround that's easy and does exactly what you need: get the wireless driver loaded automatically after resuming from suspend:

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Type the following command followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, typing your user password when prompted:

   echo 'SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES r8712u"' | sudo tee /etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules

Note: this assumes you don't already have an `/etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules` file, since otherwise it will overwrite it. Alternatively, you can create/edit the file with your text editor of choice and with `sudo` access.

What this will do is to force the module specified in the file to unload before suspending, and it will then be loaded upon resume.